# Problemas con para transportar aplicación de Angular 4

Tags: angular

Tengo problemas para transportar un proyecto de Angular de una computadora a otra, ya que al momento de querer compilarla me muestra el error de "no se encuentra el archivo angular.json". Me imagino que quizá sea una versión desfasada o no permita copiarla en otra, ¿acaso no debería? Disculpen mi ignorancia.

Comment: Al pasarlo de un ordenador a otro has actualizado tu Angular de 4 a 6, ya que ese fichero es de angular.json, donde en el 4 es angular-cli.json

Comment: Seguramente la versión que tenías anteriormente era menos a v6 de Angular. Para que funciones necesitas un archivo `angular.json` válido. Para crear el archivo y preparar lo demás sigue los pasos [aquí mencionados](https://update.angular.io/) (en inglés).

Comment: Esos pasos ya los había seguido anteriormente pero por alguna razón no me permite actualizar... Intentaré nuevamente.

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente la versión que tenías anteriormente era menos a v6 de Angular.

Para que funciones necesitas un archivo `angular.json` válido.

Para crear el archivo y preparar lo demás sigue los pasos [aquí mencionados](https://update.angular.io/) (en inglés).

Comment: Esos pasos ya los había seguido anteriormente pero por alguna razón no me permite actualizar... Intentaré nuevamente.